Recursive R function and its Python translation behave differently
Here is a recursive R function involving a matrix S from the parent environment:
f <- function(m, k, n) {
  if(n == 0) {
    return(100)
  }
  if(m == 1) {
    return(0)
  }
  if(!is.na(S[m, n])) {
    return(S[m, n])
  }
  s <- f(m-1, 1, n)
  i <- k
  while(i <= 5) {
    if(n > 2) {
      s <- s + f(m, i, n-1)
    } else {
      s <- s + f(m-1, 1, n-1)
    }
    i <- i + 1
  }
  if(k == 1) {
    S[m, n] <- s
  }
  return(s)
}

Here is the result of a call to this function:
> n <- 4
> S <- matrix(NA_real_, nrow = n, ncol = n)
> f(n, 1, n)
[1] 127500

Now, here is the Python version:
import numpy as np
def f(m, k, n):
  if n == 0:
    return 100
  if m == 1:
    return 0
  if S[m-1, n-1] is not None: 
    return S[m-1, n-1]
  s = f(m-1, 1, n)
  i = k
  while i <= 5:
    if n > 2:
      s = s + f(m, i, n-1)
    else:
      s = s + f(m-1, 1, n-1)
    i = i + 1
  if k == 1:
    S[m-1, n-1] = s
  return s

The call:
>>> n = 4
>>> S = np.full((n, n), None)
>>> f(n, 1, n)
312500

The Python result is different from the R result. Why?
One gets identical results if one replaces
  if S[m-1, n-1] is not None: 
    return S[m-1, n-1]

with
  if k == 1 and S[m-1, n-1] is not None: 
    return S[m-1, n-1]

I also have a C++ version of this function, and it has the same behavior as the R function.

just glancing at the code, but I suspect that the issue is that negative indices are meaningful in Python and in R, but they do totally different things

and just as an aside, here, but using numpy is absolutely not what you should be doing here

also, Python uses 0 -based indexing, so I don't think your if n == 0: base-cases are equivalent.

R starts iteration at 1, while Python starts at 0

The asker knows that, as can be seen from their code.

"I also have a C++ version of this function, and it has the same behavior as the R function." that is surprising, because I find the R behaviour to be the odd one. Could you share your C++ version.

Side-effects such as a function modifying external state are a code smell. Your R code doesn't do this but your Python code does.
Assignment to outer scope variables within a function scope can behave differently in R to Python (and actually within R and Python depending on whether the object is mutable).
Instinctively I feel uncomfortable that without passing S as an argument you're modifying it within the function, with S[m, n] <- s in R and S[m-1, n-1] = s in Python.
Here's a simpler example where we define S as a matrix containing one value, 0, which we increment every time we call a recursive function. The function, f(), has one parameter, k. It calls itself k times, incrementing the only value in S every time. First in R:
S <- matrix(0)

f <- function(k) {
    if (k == 1) {
        return(S)
    }
    S[1,1] <- S[1,1] + 1
    f(k - 1)
}

f(5)
#      [,1]
# [1,]    0

The output is 0 and will always be zero no matter how many times you call the function, as S is only modified in the function scope. Conversely, in Python:
S = np.zeros((1,1))
def f(k):
    if k == 1:
        print(S)
        return
    
    S[0,0] += 1
    f(k - 1)

f(5)
# [[4.]]

As you can see, even though we modify S[0,0] within the function and do not pass it as a parameter, this actually modifies it in the outer scope (or parent environment in R terms).
This may or may not be the reason for the difference in your example - your code has a lot of moving parts. But I would not expect R and Python to behave the same way when modifying variables in this way. More generally, I think you'd need a pretty compelling reason to write code which references (let alone modifies) variables from within a function without passing them as arguments.

You're right, this is the correct explanation. Thanks!

I think python is running a different mechanism for mutable object, and probably you can refer to this document
https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-did-changing-list-y-also-change-list-x

In other words:
If we have a mutable object (list, dict, set, etc.), we can use some
specific operations to mutate it and all the variables that refer to
it will see the change.
If we have an immutable object (str, int, tuple, etc.), all the
variables that refer to it will always see the same value, but
operations that transform that value into a new value always return a
new object.

My understanding is that, in your python translation, S is a mutable object and thus is annotated in the function in each recursion layer (without any further calls or assignments). In this case, it seems equivalent to the treatment to a global variable in R. This is revealed in @SamR's answer already. You can check S in both python and R, e.g.,

in python

# print(f(n,1,n))
312500

# S
array([[None, None, None, None],
       [500, 0, 0, 0],
       [1000, 2500, 12500, 62500],
       [None, 7500, 50000, 312500]], dtype=object)



in R

> f(n, 1, n)
[1] 127500

> S
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA


I don't think the R code gives the desired output but believe that the python code should give the correct one. In your R code, you can use <<- rather than <- when updating the entries of S, and you will see that R and python yield the same output.
f <- function(m, k, n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return(100)
    }
    if (m == 1) {
        return(0)
    }
    if (!is.na(S[m, n])) {
        return(S[m, n])
    }
    s <- f(m - 1, 1, n)
    i <- k
    while (i <= 5) {
        if (n > 2) {
            s <- s + f(m, i, n - 1)
        } else {
            s <- s + f(m - 1, 1, n - 1)
        }
        i <- i + 1
    }
    if (k == 1) {
        S[m, n] <<- s # use `<<-` to update the "global" `S`
    }
    return(s)
}

and you will obtain
> n <- 4

> S <- matrix(NA, n, n)

> f(n, 1, n)
[1] 312500


Good point (+1). But in my real code, the correct result is the R result. So I don't want that the R code behaves like the Python code, I want the opposite.

@StéphaneLaurent see my latest answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/78487680/12158757

To start, I am not too familiar with R code, but it seems like an incorrect conversion from R to Python causing a one-off error. The python code below yields the same result as the R code you supplied. Pay particular attention to the if k == 0: line, this is more accurate
*Edit: it appears the R programming language starts it's array index at 1 instead of 0 like most programming languages, as stefan-aus-hannover &
juanpa.arrivillaga said (https://stackoverflow.com/users/2868899/stefan-aus-hannover,
https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014455/juanpa-arrivillaga).
1-off illustration
import numpy as np

def f(m, k, n):
  if n == 0:
    return 100
  if m == 1:
    return 0
  if S[m-1, n-1] is not None: 
    return S[m-1, n-1]
  s = f(m-1, 1, n)
  i = k
  while i <= 5:
    if n > 2:
      s = s + f(m, i, n-1)
    else:
      s = s + f(m-1, 1, n-1)
    i = i + 1
  if k == 0:
    S[m, n] = s
  return s

n = 4
S = np.full((n, n), None)
print(f(n, 1, n))

Note the difference in the last if statement (if k == 0 instead of if k == 1, and S[m, n] = s instead of S[m-1, n-1] = s).

R does not mutate the global S variable when you do S[m, n] <- s. See Global variables in R. If you would comment out the only statement that attempts to mutate S, like so:
# S[m, n] <- s

... then it would still produce the same result (127500 in your example call). This is a strong hint that the author of that R code did not achieve what they really intended.
The shortest modification to make your R code to really make modifications to the non-local S, is replacing the assignment operator with a scoping assignment operator:
S[m, n] <<- s

Now it will also output 312500 like the Python code does.
I ignore here that it is bad practice to mutate global state in a function.

Here is just a follow-up answer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/78457272/12158757

If the R code is really the one you are after and you want to make the python version align with the R code, you should first investigate if matrix S is ever necessary.
My observation is that: You don't need S in your R code at all, indeed!
You can try removing all the S-related statements from f, like below
f <- function(m, k, n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return(100)
    }
    if (m == 1) {
        return(0)
    }

    s <- f(m - 1, 1, n)
    i <- k
    while (i <= 5) {
        if (n > 2) {
            s <- s + f(m, i, n - 1)
        } else {
            s <- s + f(m - 1, 1, n - 1)
        }
        i <- i + 1
    }
    return(s)
}

and you will see that S is independent with your recursion
> n <- 4

> f(n, 1, n)
[1] 127500

which can be proved from the values in S after running f as well (see the output example shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/78457272/12158757), since your f function actually never mutates the values in S during the recursions.

On top of the analysis above, you can simply do the same in your python translation
import numpy as np

def f(m, k, n):
    if n == 0:
        return 100
    if m == 1:
        return 0
    s = f(m - 1, 1, n)
    i = k
    while i <= 5:
        if n > 2:
            s += f(m, i, n - 1)
        else:
            s += f(m - 1, 1, n - 1)
        i += 1
    return s

say, don't S in your python environment to avoid confusions, and you will get the desired output
# print(f(4,1,4))
127500

